# Cabeçalho da tabela thead não alinha com as linhas depois do append

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5, tabela-html

Estou com um problema no código,

Preciso alinhar as tags do Thead na minha tabela que recebe um json de todos os dados, os dados estão vindo e o cabeçalho está lá, porém ambos não ficam alinhados, preciso de uma ajuda.

Codigo html Tabela:

```
<div id="main-table-editaprod">

    <table id="tabela-produtos" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">   
                <thead>                          
                      <tr>
                                          <th data-column-id="id_prod">Id</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="nome_prod_curto">Nome Curto</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="nome_prod_longo">Nome Longo</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="codigo_interno">Código Interno</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="cate">Categoria</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="preco">Preço</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="peso">Peso</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="largura_centimetro">Largura (cm)</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="altura_centimetro">Altura (cm)</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="quantidade_estoque">Quantidade Estoque</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="preco_promorcional">Preço Promorcional</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="foto_principal">Foto</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="visivel">Visivel</th>
                                          <th data-column-id="comprimento_centimetro">Comprimento (cm)</th>
                                        <th>&nbsp;</th>'
                        </tr>


              </thead>

          <tbody></tbody>

    </table>
```

Codigo jquery :

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/editarprod-todos',function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, v){


    $('#tabela-produtos tbody').append("<tr><td id='id_prod' name='id_prod'>"+v.id_prod+"<td>"+
                                            "<td id='nome_prod_curto'>"+'<input type="text" name="nome_prod_curto" value='+v.nome_prod_curto+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td id='nome_prod_longo'>"+'<input type="text" name="nome_prod_longo" value='+v.nome_prod_longo+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="codigo_interno" class="table-editaprod-number2" value='+v.codigo_interno+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="text" name="id_cat" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.id_cat+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="preco" class="table-editaprod-number2" value='+v.preco+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="peso" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.peso+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="largura_centimetro" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.largura_centimetro+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="altura_centimetro" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.altura_centimetro+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="quantidade_estoque" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.quantidade_estoque+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="preco_promorcional" class="table-editaprod-number2" value='+v.preco_promorcional+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="file" name="foto_principal" value='+v.foto_principal+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="text" name="visivel" value='+v.visivel+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="text" name="comprimento_centimetro" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.comprimento_centimetro+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                      "<td>"+'<input type="button"  id="editarProdForm" value="Editar" name="editar"></input>'+"<td></tr>")


    });

    });

});
```

Comment: É mais fácil se copiar o html final e dizer o que pretende mudar nele. Nós não temos o link do getJSON para testar.

Comment: Amigo um conselho, utilize a jquery-tmpl pra fazer bind com dados json, essa lib não recebe atualizações a um bom tempo mas sempre utilizei ela e nunca tive problemas. https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

Comment: @loops Conforme falei fazendo desse modo com o apend os dados vem normalmente do web serviçe porém o cabeçalho da thead os <th> não ficam alinhados com esse apend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, o problema é bem simples...
Você esqueceu de fechar as tags , por exemplo:

```
    // Essa linha: 
    <td id='id_prod' name='id_prod'>"+v.id_prod+"<td>"
    // Deve ficar assim:
    <td id='id_prod' name='id_prod'>"+v.id_prod+"</td>"
```

E gostaria de dar um conselho, no seu loop each ao invés de colocar o append em todas as iterações do loop vc pode colocar fora que funciona melhor e é mais performático.

```
 // Cria uma variável antes do each
 var html = "";
  $.each(data, function(k, v){ 
     // Eu nao adicionei os fechamentos do td ta bom, é só um exemplo.
     html += "<tr><td id='id_prod' name='id_prod'>"+v.id_prod+"<td>"+
                                            "<td id='nome_prod_curto'>"+'<input type="text" name="nome_prod_curto" value='+v.nome_prod_curto+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td id='nome_prod_longo'>"+'<input type="text" name="nome_prod_longo" value='+v.nome_prod_longo+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="codigo_interno" class="table-editaprod-number2" value='+v.codigo_interno+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="text" name="id_cat" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.id_cat+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="preco" class="table-editaprod-number2" value='+v.preco+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="peso" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.peso+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="largura_centimetro" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.largura_centimetro+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="altura_centimetro" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.altura_centimetro+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="quantidade_estoque" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.quantidade_estoque+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="preco_promorcional" class="table-editaprod-number2" value='+v.preco_promorcional+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="file" name="foto_principal" value='+v.foto_principal+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="text" name="visivel" value='+v.visivel+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="text" name="comprimento_centimetro" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.comprimento_centimetro+'></input>'+"<td>"+
                      "<td>"+'<input type="button"  id="editarProdForm" value="Editar" name="editar"></input>'+"<td></tr>"
  });

//Após o each vc adiciona o html na sua tabela
$('#tabela-produtos tbody').html(html);
```

Comment: Vish que lerdeza a minha kkkkk era isso mesmo nossa e eu quebrando a cabeça com força, valeu mano !

Comment: tmj, qualquer coisa é só bipa. haha